# Tkinter - can't open multiple photos at the same time (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, photos

im trying to open multiple photos at the same time in Python:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text="this is the root window").pack()
root.geometry("200x200")

for i in range(1, 6):
    loc = os.getcwd() + '\pictures\pic%s.jpg'%(i)
    img = Image.open(loc)
    img.load()
    photoimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    window = tk.Toplevel()
    window.geometry("200x200")
    tk.Label(window, text="this is window %s" % i).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It opens 5 windows as needed (not including root window), but the pictures doesn't show up.
Suggestions? Thnx in advance

Comment: Which widget do you want the image to be in, as you haven't placed it in any widget.  See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm and http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm

Comment: you  load image but you don't add it to window

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a label with the argument `image=photoimg` onto the window for the image to show up.

Your code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text="this is the root window").pack()
root.geometry("200x200")

for i in range(1, 6):
    loc = os.getcwd() + '\pictures\pic%s.jpg'%(i)
    img = Image.open(loc)
    img.load()
    photoimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    window = tk.Toplevel()
    window.geometry("200x200")
    tk.Label(window, text="this is window %s" % i).pack()
    tk.Label(window, image=photoimg).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying. However, it displays only the last photo and the problem remains with the others. I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Along with adding `image=photoimg` like Jonah Fleming said, you have to keep a reference to each PhotoImage, or they will be garbage collected when the `photoimg` variable is assigned to another PhotoImage. The simplest way to bypass this problem is to keep the PhotoImage instances in a list. That would be done like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text="this is the root window").pack()
root.geometry("200x200")

photoimage_list = [] # Create a list to hold the PhotoImages!

for i in range(1, 6):
    loc = os.getcwd() + '\pictures\pic%s.jpg'%(i)
    img = Image.open(loc)
    img.load()
    photoimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    photoimg.append(photoimage_list) # Add it to a list so it isn't garbage collected!!
    window = tk.Toplevel()
    window.geometry("200x200")
    tk.Label(window, text="this is window %s" % i).pack()
    tk.Label(window, image=photoimg).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Just make sure that the `photoimage_list` list doesn't get garbage collected, so don't have the list ever be deleted/lose all of its strong references.

You can read more about garbage collection at https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/.